# Visual c# 2010 displaying balance from sql database to label

Tags: c#

i want to to display the balance from the database to a label.

here my code i got so far

```
SqlDataReader readbalance; 

        sqlCommandbalance.Connection.Open();
        sqlCommandbalance.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE accountID = '" + dataSet11.Tables[0].Rows[0]["accountID"] + "'";
        readbalance = sqlCommandbalance.ExecuteReader();
        string balanceDB = null;
        while (readbalance.Read()) 
        {
            balanceDB = readbalance["balance"].ToString();
        }
        sqlCommandbalance.Connection.Close();
        balanceShow.Text += "" + balanceDB.ToString();;
```

i am having a problem on this line
    sqlCommandbalance.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE accountID = '" + dataSet11.Tables[0].Rows[0]["accountID"] + "'";

keep saying cnt find row at position 0 but i am testing this code on the commandtext dataSet11.Tables[0].Rows[0]["accountID"] not sure if it right or not

Answer (score 0):

It means one or more of parameters `accountID, balance, overdraftLimit` must be an integer and you are setting string value of it.

Comment: accountID - INT, balance - money overdraftlimit - money

Comment: and you are setting balanceShow.Text value of all?

Comment: Whats the value of `balanceShow.Text`? Its looks like a not-integer, that means you cannot convert it to integer and cannot set this value to these parameters. So what you have to do is, set integer value like `12` to `@accountID`, double like `12.5` to `balance` and `overdraftLimit` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

use `int.Parse(balanceShow.Text)`

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, buy maybe what you need is something like this:

```
SqlDataReader readdata;
sqlCommandCheckBalance.Parameters["@accountID"].Value = accountID;
sqlCommandCheckBalance.Connection.Open(); 
readdata = sqlCommandCheckBalance.ExecuteReader();
while (readdata.Read())
{
    balanceShow.Text += " " + readdata["balance"].ToString();
}
```